# Not able to switch to super user in terminal From robot framework

Tags: ssh, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

```
Open Connection    192.***.***.**
Login    ****    *******
Start Command    su hdfs
Execute Command    cd /home/rajesh/hive-latest/
${STDOUT1}    Execute Command    ls -lrt
Log    ${STDOUT1}
Close Connection
```

*Here i am able to login. after login, not able to switch to super user. without switching to super user, its executing ls -lrt. Please help me with this if anyone knows

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the ssh library works. Have a look at the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Execute%20Command)

> The command is always executed in a new shell. Thus possible changes
> to the environment (e.g. changing working directory) are not visible
> to the later keywords

You can work around this by executing the command as different user, or if possible you can open another connection and login as desired user.

```
su - <username> -c "<commands>"
```

Comment: Hi Jiri. I am login as root user. then i am trying to switch to another user by using "su hdfs". this user not required password.  But i am unable to switch to this "hdfs" user

Comment: your command should look like this "Execute Command    su hdfs -c 'ls -lrt /home/sunil/hive-latest/'"

Comment: Hi Jiri. Its working fine now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: glad i could help, you can mark the answer if it was a solution to your problem.

Comment: After getting list. its again pointing to root only if go with pwd. I am using this below command to move to hive-latest directory. Its not working

Comment: I am using this command su hdfs -c 'cd /home/sunil/hive-latest/'

Comment: that is how the library works, as i pointed out from the documentation. Each command is executed in new shell, you cannot change working directory.

Comment: Hi Jiri. Thank you so much for info. Is there any other library that supports changing working directory in robot framework?

Comment: you can use this one in the way i have described it. Or you can try to describe in detail what exactly it is that you need.

Comment: Hi Jiri. I am trying to execute some spark job in the place of ls-lrt in the below command.     su hdfs -c 'ls -lrt /home/sunil/hive-latest/'"   ....its working fine for ls -lrt .. not working for my spark job.  Please help me if you can